# How to get the position of the cursor in a ComboBox when the user sets the cursor using the mouse or arrow keys?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, textbox

I have a ComboBox containing text.
I would like to know when the user uses the mouse or the arrow key, at which character (which column) the user placed the cursor.

```
int column = textBox1.SelectionStart - textBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(1);
```

only works for TextBoxes. Is there anything similar for ComboBox?
I assumed that the TextBox of a ComboBox behaves like a regular TextBox but I was wrong.

Comment: Those are all methods of the [TextBoxBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase) class. E.g., `GetCharIndexFromPosition()` + those methods wou have already mentioned -- What a line is, depends on what you're working on. If it's the logical line, then you can use these methods, that's what the Control uses itself. If it's the physical line, then you may have a problem, because neither the TextBox or the RichTextBox really deal with those on the outside: you only have the Lines[] array, something you better don't touch or touch with great care.

Comment: If you just want to know when a User performs an action using the Keyboard or Mouse, e.g., to updated a status bar, then handle the related events. The methods to call and the properties to read are still the same.

Comment: @Jimi I do NOT only want to know that the user used the keyboard or the mouse. As I stated in the title and in the body of the question, my purpose is to find out  at least the column where the cursor is positioned at te end of the user's action.

Comment: There must be something missing here, because this statement: *only works when the user types something but not when he uses the mouse or the arrow keys to position the cursor* is simply not true: the caret position is always read using the same properties, not matter how or when the caret is moved. You should probably specify what this code is used for, when you want to read the caret position and how it happens you cannot get in this context.